Understanding divisors in tropical geometry
I've been studying tropical geometry recently, and I found the divisor idea, but I don't really get it, and also, I didn't find good examples. If you can explain me this idea, and give me some intuitive examples, I'd be so grateful. Thanks in advance.

You want intuitive examples and it's simplest to have intuitive examples using (tropical) curves.
Definitions. A tropical divisor on a tropical curve $\Gamma$ is a "formal sum" of points $p\in\Gamma$ with integer coefficients, i.e., $D$ is a divisor on $\Gamma$ iff
$$ D = \sum_{p\in\Gamma} a_p\,[p]\,, $$
where all coefficients $a_p\in\Bbb Z$ and only finitely many of the $a_p$ are non-zero for any given $D$. (In other words, divisors are elements of the free abelian group on the set of points $\{[p]\}$ of $\Gamma$, let's denote this by $\Bbb Z\Gamma$.)
A principal divisor on a tropical curve $\Gamma$ is the divisor associated with a tropical rational function. (A tropical rational function is just a piece-wise linear function $f: \Gamma \to \Bbb R$ with integer slopes.) The principal divisor $(f)$ of $f$ is formed by taking the "formal sum" of the points where $f$ has non-zero slope changes (critical points), weighted by the magnitude of these slope changes. (Formally, as before, the principal divisor $(f)$ of $f$ is given by an element of a subgroup of $\Bbb Z\Gamma$, i.e., it has the form:
$$ (f) = \sum_{p \in \Gamma} \Delta_p(f)\,[p]\,, $$
where $\Delta_p(f)$ is the change in the slope of $f$ at point $p$.)

Example. Consider the tropical line $\Gamma$ defined by $ \min(x, y, 0) = 0 $. One possible tropical rational function on $\Gamma$ is $ f(x, y) = \min(x, y) $. We find the principal divisor $(f)$ by identifying the points where the slope of $f$ changes and the magnitude of these changes. With some quick work, this is:
$$
(f) = 1 \cdot [(0, 0)] - 1 \cdot [(-1, 0)] - 1 \cdot [(0, -1)] 
$$
This indicates that the principal divisor consists of:

A point at the origin $(0, 0)$ with coefficient $1$,
Points at $(-1, 0)$ and $(0, -1)$ each with coefficient $-1$.

The divisor indicates that the function has a critical point at the origin and decreases in slope by $1$ unit in both the $x$- and $y$-direction as you move away from the origin along the negative axes.

It is to be noted that the above definitions also generalize for higher dimensions using classical algebraic geometric language. Since the OP is asking for a "reputable source", here I list a couple resources on tropical geometry (TG):

A great introductory reference (with minimal prerequisites) is Introduction to Tropical Geometry by Maclagen & Strumfels.
Tropical Geometry and Its Applications is a great exposition by G. Mikhalkin (at some point you must start reading his work if you want to keep going into TG).

There are other more formal/advanced treatments of TG as well. But I think the OP is looking for introductory/intuitive references and these are a great place to start. If OP wants more advanced treatments, one could start by looking at the references section of this nLab article. Hope this answers OP's questions.

Are the points $(-1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$ on $\Gamma$? they don't satisfy $\min(x,y,0)=0$.
